# Access config.rb from Javascript in Middleman

Tags: javascript, ruby, middleman

I've set the following configuration in the config.rb

```
config[:remote_domain] = "localhost:3000"
```

which I can access without any problems in my view like this:

```
<%= config[:remote_domain] %>
```

Why is it not possible to access the config object in my javascript file? When I try to call:

```
console.log( "<%= config[:remote_domain] %>" );
```

I get the error:

```
throw Error("NameError: uninitialized constant ERB::App\n  on line 3 of /Users/.../source/javascripts/_access_request.js.erb)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
console.log( "<%= j config[:remote_domain] %>" );
```

`j` will escape string for javascript

Comment: still not working ... gives back the exact same error message

Comment: @PeterPiper Weird. Another option that i can think of would be to assign in to a variable in a controller and pass it to javascript. Or use gem like Gon that will do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use the extension `.js.erb` instead of `.js`.

While running `middleman build`, whatever inside `<%=  %>` will get evaluated to corresponding values just as in say `.html.erb`